# MassTransit extending

Tags: inversion-of-control, masstransit

I am using Unity with Masstransit. I need to register context-specific data in container so it can be injected as consumer constructor parameters.
Is it possible to get into Masstransit consumer lifecycle at the moment consumer is just about to be built up to register some stuff in Unity container used for consumer constructing?